# How to share a variable between several preprocess functions in dot theme file

Tags: hooks

I retrieve config settings that are used in two different regions. How can I get the setting once and then pass it to two different hooks?

Now I get the setting in each hook and it seems to be not quite DRY.

```
function te23_preprocess_region__navbar(&$variables) {

  $general_info = \Drupal::config('te.settings')->get('general_info');
  $variables['email'] = \Drupal::service('te.helper_functions')->render_email($general_info['email']);  
  $variables['tel_link'] = \Drupal::service('te.helper_functions')->render_phone_number($general_info['phone_number']);

}

function te23_preprocess_region__footer(&$variables) {
  $general_info = \Drupal::config('te.settings')->get('general_info');
  $reviews = \Drupal::config('te.settings')->get('reviews');
  $variables['reviews'] = $reviews;
  $variables['address'] = $general_info['address'];
  $variables['email'] = \Drupal::service('te.helper_functions')->render_email($general_info['email']); 
  $variables['tel_link'] = \Drupal::service('te.helper_functions')->render_phone_number($general_info['phone_number']);
  
}
```

Comment: I guess you're overthinking this. Just create a helper function in your .theme file and call the helper from both hooks

Comment: Well, I guess that's what I did. The problem was that I requested the same data twice (each time for each region). As per @4uk4 answer I used a more general region hook and now the data are requested once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, hooks are not connected and don't share variables. In this case, however, both hooks are for the same base hook, so you can run the preprocess hook for the base hook `mymodule_preprecess_region()` and handle both regions, check `$variables['region']`, with DRY.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand regions a bit better.